# Activate the virtual environment through the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, command-line, environment

I have a problem to Activate the virtual environment through the command line,I did it before and this problem didn`t appear to me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdJmj.png)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>cd projects\django_pm

C:\Users\user\projects\django_pm>pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570]

(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

**(user-KgVmIwbj) C:\Users\user>`**
```

I try to create new virtual environments

Comment: Can you add what exactly is your problem that you are facing?

Comment: Be more specific as your title (activate an env) contradicts the question in the content (create an env).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.